# Streaming audio between apps in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, streaming, sip, aidl

Hello sages of the Overflowing Stack, Android noob here..

I'm using CSipSimple and want to stream the call audio to another app, in chunks of 1 second audio data so that it can process the raw pcm data.
The code that handles the audio in CSipSimple is native, so I prefer using native approaches and not callback Java.
I thought of a few ways of doing so:

1. Use audio streaming and let the other app get it.
2. Writing the data to a file and let the other app read it.
3. Calling a service in the other application (AIDL)
4. Using intents.

These are the considerations leading to my dillema:
Streaming looks like the natural choice, but I couldn't find Android support for retrieving raw pcm data from an an audio stream. The intent mechanism is flexible and convenient, but I don't think that that's what they're meant for. Using a file seems cumbersome, although it's well supported. Finally, using a service seems like a good option but it seems less flexible and probably needs more error handling and thread management.

Can you guys point out the best alternative?
If you have another one you're welcome to share it..

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about the streaming audio API support so I'll not touch this case.
As for writing data to a file and let other application to read it - this is a possible case how to solve your problem.

As for calling service through AIDL and using intents, I do not think that this is a good solution. The problem is that Binder has a limitation over the size of the data (1MB) that can be passed in a transaction.

To my point of view, the best solution (especially if you're working in native) is to use AshMem. This is a shared memory driver developed specifically for Android. Thus, in your service you create a shared memory region and pass the reference to it into your client app that reads information from the this memory.